# Why I would be getting a "method_missing" error when calling "should respond_with :success" in context block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing, shoulda

Here is a gist of the error and test:  https://gist.github.com/1445801

And here are the gist contents:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::HotelsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    context "When not logged in" do
        should "forbid access when creating a hotel" do
            hotel = Factory.build(:hotel)
            post :create, :hotel => hotel
            assert @response.code == "401"
            assert Hotel.count.zero?
        end

        should "forbid access when listing available hotels" do
            get :available
            assert @response.code == "401"
        end

        should "forbid access when listing hotels" do
            get :index
            assert @response.code == "401"
        end

        should "forbid access when showing a hotel" do
            hotel = Factory(:hotel)
            get :show, :id => hotel.id
            assert @response.code == "401"
        end

        should "forbid when updating a hotel" do
            hotel = Factory(:hotel)
            hotel.name = "Some new Hotel name"
            put :update, :id => hotel.id, :hotel => hotel
            assert @response.code == "401"
        end
  end

    context "When logged in as basic user" do
        setup do
            @user = Factory(:user)
            sign_in @user
        end

        context "on GET available hotel with no search criteria" do
            setup do
                get :available
            end

            should respond_with :success
            should "be valid response" do
                true
            end
        end
    end

end
```

And the test:

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "addresses_id_seq" for serial column "addresses.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "addresses_pkey" for table "addresses"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "amenities_id_seq" for serial column "amenities.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "amenities_pkey" for table "amenities"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "hotels_id_seq" for serial column "hotels.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "hotels_pkey" for table "hotels"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "locations_id_seq" for serial column "locations.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "locations_pkey" for table "locations"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "photos_id_seq" for serial column "photos.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "photos_pkey" for table "photos"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "rooms_id_seq" for serial column "rooms.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "rooms_pkey" for table "rooms"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "user_hotel_taggings_id_seq" for serial column "user_hotel_taggings.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "user_hotel_taggings_pkey" for table "user_hotel_taggings"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare 
** Execute test:functionals
/Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:429:in `method_missing': undefined method `respond_with' for Api::HotelsControllerTest:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/test/functional/api/hotels_controller_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:HotelsControllerTest>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:306:in `call'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:306:in `merge_block'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:301:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:310:in `new'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:310:in `context'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/test/functional/api/hotels_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:HotelsControllerTest>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:306:in `call'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:306:in `merge_block'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:301:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:199:in `new'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/shoulda-2.11.3/lib/shoulda/context.rb:199:in `context'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/test/functional/api/hotels_controller_test.rb:37:in `<class:HotelsControllerTest>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/test/functional/api/hotels_controller_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/Eric/Work/webapp/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare 
** Execute test:integration
Errors running test:functionals!
rake test TESTOPTS="-v" --trace  14.58s user 1.96s system 89% cpu 18.499 total
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the `shoulda-matchers` gem installed and it comes after the `rspec` gem in the gemfile?

Comment: I am not using rspec. Here is the contents of my Gemfile https://gist.github.com/1445981.

Comment: Don't you have to include both `rspec-rails` and `shoulda-matcher` in your Gemfile? (From the `shoulda-matcher` gem `README.rdoc` https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)

Comment: @buruzaemon I didn't think so. I am modeling my tests off of how rubygems.org (https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org) is written and they don't seem to reference rspec anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try including brackets around :success, `should respond_with(:success)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue (with the same version of Shoulda -- 2.11.3 -- and with a namespaced controller like you) and fixed it by upgrading Shoulda to 3.1.1.